# Can't we use raw push notifications to trigger backgroundTask without adding LockScreen in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, microsoft-metro

Is there any way to start `BackgroundTask` when the raw push notification is received. I don't want to add lock screen app feature. Please help me.